# Does Fortify takes long time while "Generating Intermediate Files"

Tags: fortify

I am using Fortify for security scan one of our cSharp application and it is taking hours while "Generating Intermediate Files" I am not sure it is hung or really doing something. Does it really take such a long time?

Answer (score 2):

Generating intermediate files at the start of a .NET build is usually when SCA is creating NST files for the library functions used. This should only really need to occur once per project per machine although after the first project it shouldn't take that long. Then they will be stored in `${fortify.ProjectRoot}/sca<version>/build/Libraries/` as long as this isn't deleted (and you don't run `sourceanalyzer -clean` (as in cleaning without a build ID) then they should be in here for subsequent scans.
Increasing memory options may help you, but I would advise to just let it run and then see how it goes in subsequent scans.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without specific details on your scan setup and Fortify version, it's difficult to say specifically what's causing the long scan time. However, some factors do impact the scan time for Fortify:

- complexity of the code base. Large, complex code bases definitely take a while longer to translate and analyze than trivial code
- memory allocated to the Fortify scan process. Fortify sourceanalyzer scans can be fairly memory intensive
- local system load

Do you have any additional details that you can share about your scan?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following options to reduce dramatically the duration :

```
"-Xmx20g" (or mot if you have more memory) and "-64" for 64-bit processor
```